# How do I set a value to a variable in a method and print it out in the main method?

Tags: java, variables, methods

```
public class Shape 
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int num = 0;
        cng(num);
    }

    public static void cng(int x){
        x = 52;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

As you can see, in the `cng` Method I set the value of x to 52 and then print out the value of x.

Then, back in the main method, the `cng` method is performed on the `num` variable.

What I want to do, however is set the value of 52 to x without the `System.out.println(x);`
function in my `cng` method and print out the value in my `main` method. How would I go about doing that?

I tried doing

```
public static void cng(int x){
    x = 52;
}
```

and then

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int num = 0;
    cng(num);
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

but it only prints out a 0
because num is set to 0. I thought that performing `cng` on the `num` variable would change it to 52, but it doesn't.

Comment: It changes a copy. Make num a field.

Comment: change return type of `cng()` to int, and return int from `cng()` to main method

Comment: [Immutable objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) can not be changed like this, Please also read [is java pass by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read along the comments :

```
public class Shape 
{

    public static void main(String args[]){
    int num = 0;
    num = cng();   //store value returned by cng() in num
    System.out.println("num : " +num); // display num
    }

    public static int cng(){    //change return type to int
    return 52;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

make your cng method return an int variable

```
public static int cng(int num){    
num = 52; 
return num; 
}
```

In Your Main method, assign the returned variable from cng() method

```
int num = 0;
 num =cng(num);
 System.out.println(num);
```

Or:

you could always, make num as a member static variable,

```
   static int num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass the data by reference. This is not possible for primitive values in Java (int, double, boolean, etc).

You have the following options:

- Make it a member of the class
- Create a wrapper object (object references are also passed by value, **but** you **can** change the members of that object in a function, just not the object reference itself)
- Return the value in the function (as mentioned by other answers)

Comment: partly wrong, Objects are not passed by reference in java . java is always, pass by value in case of both objects and primitives. here's a very good explanation i would suggest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR : oppa gangnam style . You might wany tp refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: Actually correct most would be to say : java passes object refferences by value.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR : yea , i think it is neither objects by value nor object as reference it is object references by value. Just for a ref: i posted before you edited ypur initial commemt :-)

Comment: I knew it is like Mukul Goel stated, but I thought that was a bit too complicated for the questioner. In practice it boils down to objects being passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to this:

```
public class Shape 
{


public static void main(String args[]){
    int num = 0;
    num = cng(num);
    System.out.println(num);
}

public static int cng(int x){
    x = 52;
    return x;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour is that arguments are passed by value in Java. This implies that it is simply a copy of the variable that you passed to it. Thus the assignment that you do is only local to the method.